# Handle comma separated string

Tags: android

Creating an app in which i want to get string from json but i have one key and multiple value so i don't know how to handle this.

```
"colours": "#fff600,#000000,#ffffff,#00000,#ff9900,#333333"
```

And want to use this color in different class:

```
final ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new android.animation.ArgbEvaluator(), Color.RED, Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN,Color.MAGENTA,Color.GREEN,Color.GRAY);
    colorAnimation.setDuration(1400);
```

Comment: use json arrays: "colours": ["#fff600","#000000","#ffffff","#00000","#ff9900","#333333"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the value of colours in string variable and then split the string in following way and add it to an arraylist :

```
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr1.add(arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: How to set here  final ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new android.animation.ArgbEvaluator(), Color.RED, Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN,Color.MAGENTA,Color.GREEN,Color.GRAY);
    colorAnimation.setDuration(1400);

Comment: Do you have to use all colors here itself? Inside ValueAnimator.ofObject() ??

Comment: //Yes i have to use all colors here like in place of Color.WHITE i want to use json response color "#ff6600" in place of COLOR.CYAN "#000000"

Comment: is there fix no. of colors in your json response.. or it will vary?

Comment: Ok then you can use the following code there : 

 final ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new android.animation.ArgbEvaluator(), Color.parseColor(arr1.get(0)), Color.parseColor(arr1.get(1)),Color.parseColor(arr1.get(2)),Color.parseColor(arr1.get(3)),Color.parseColor(arr1.get(4)),Color.parseColor(arr1.get(5))​); colorAnimation.setDuration(1400);

Answer (score 1):

Get value of color and use string tokenizer with ',' delima like this:

```
       StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(colorValueString, ",");
```

Also it has `stringTokenizer.nextToken` to get the next color in string

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of colours as a string and then split the string into parts like this:

```
String colours = json.getString("colours");
Log.d(TAG, colours);

String items[] = colours.split(",");
for (String item : items) {
    Log.d(TAG, item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you own the json**
You should use JSONArray:

```
"colours": ["#fff600","#000000","#ffffff","#00000","#ff9900","#333333"]
```

And read it like

```
    JSONObject json = ...;
    JSONArray colorsArray = json.getJSONArray("colours");
    for(int i = 0; i < colorsArray.length(); i++) {
        String colorString = colorsArray.getString(i);
        int color = Color.parseColor(colorString);
        // you should probably also catch IllegalArgumentException for wrong input
    }
```

**If you don't own the json**
You can read it as string and split around commas:

```
    JSONObject json = ...;
    String colorsString = json.getString("colours");
    String[] colorStrings = colorsString.split(",");
    for(String string : colorStrings) {
        int color = Color.parseColor(string);
        // you should probably also catch IllegalArgumentException for wrong input
    }
```